# Google Cloud Functions Checking for changes in Firestore at the end of the day

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a possible way to check for changes in Firestore with google cloud functions at the end of the day?

From the documentation I only can take the classic Firestore triggers(Oncreate, onchange, ondelete, onwrite).

In my app, the documents are updated many times throughout the day.
At the end of the day the documents are ready for further processing.
So my attention is to save invocations by only looking for changed documents every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in functionality to either trigger Cloud Functions daily with all documents that were modified, or even in the Firestore API to get all documents that were modified in a certain time interval.

What you can do is:

1. Add a `lastModified` field to each document that you update whenever you update that document, [setting it to the server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp).
2. Create a Cloud Function that [gets triggered every day](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).
3. In the function [run a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to Firestore that gets you all documents where  `lastModified` is in the past 24 hours.

Comment: Just a question the above topic. I have written a function which gets a Querysnapshot within all changed Documents of the past 24 hours. I loop through this Querysnapshot to get the relevant informations. The informations out of this docs I save into maps which are unique for every user. Every user generates in average 10 documents a day. So every map gets written 10 times in average. 
Now I'm wondering if the whole thing is scalable or will hit the 500 writes per transaction limit given in Firebase as more users use the app. I would be pleased about a short feedback.

Comment: Here I have the link to the limitations I am talking about:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions

Comment: You can either run the function more frequently to get fewer documents at a time, or you can count the number of documents, and start a new transaction before you reach the limit.

Comment: Does this scheduled function count as a transaction ? I have executed this script for more than 600 docs and got no error.

Comment: That's impossible to say without seeing the code. I recommend opening a new question for this implementation problem, with the [minimal **code** that anyone can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have created a new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243065/google-cloud-functions-firestore-limitations